# Why am I getting "unused default export" error?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I don't get how I'm getting `unused default export` error whenever I hover over `export default emailChanged;` in my `index.js` file.  I'm assuming this is why my code won't run in the simulator.

Here's `LoginForm.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {emailChanged} from 'TorusTeensApp/src/actions';
import {Text, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    onsubmitediting={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                    returnKeyType={"next"}
                    placeholder={"Email"}
                    label={"Email"}
                    keyboardType={"email-address"}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.email}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    ref={(userInput) => this.passwordInput = userInput}
                    returnKeyType={"go"}
                    placeholder={"Password"}
                    label={"Password"}
                    secureTextEntry
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Create Account</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20 // creates a gap from the bottom
    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#9b42f4',
        height: 40
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#41bbf4',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 20
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = state =>  {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    (dispatch) => ({emailChanged: (text) => dispatch(emailChanged(text))}))(LoginForm);
```

Here's `index.js`:

```
import {EMAIL_CHANGED} from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
        payload: text
    };
};

onEmailChange = (text) => {
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
};

export default emailChanged;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `index.js`, you have exported the  action `emailChanged` as a named export and you are again exporting the same as `default`. However you are only importing it as a named import. Thats the reason for your error.

Remove the default export for `emailChanged`.

```
import {EMAIL_CHANGED} from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
        payload: text
    };
};

onEmailChange = (text) => {
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
};
```

However, I assume that your intension was to `export default onEmailChange` function.

In that case change add

`export default onEmailChange` to the `index.js` file.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `export default emailChanged`, you can't get the value of `emailChanged` by destructing. Remove the `export default emailChanged` line in your index.js and you should be good.

Comment: It doesn't work.  If I do that and then hover over `export const emailChanged`, it gives me a `unused constant emailChanged` error.

Comment: I think you can just pass the action to the connect function. so you can try this`export default connect(mapStateToProps, emailChanged)(LoginForm)`.  I'm not too sure about this tho.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the wrong import.

replace:

`import {emailChanged} from 'TorusTeensApp/src/actions';`

with:

`import emailChanged from 'TorusTeensApp/src/actions';`

Here's a better explanation: [Difference between "import {Something} from somelib" and "import Something from somelib" React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537180/difference-between-import-something-from-somelib-and-import-something-from)