# Difference between "import {Something} from somelib" and "import Something from somelib" React.js

Tags: reactjs, import

I do not understand the difference between:

```
import {Something} from somelib
```

and

```
import Something from somelib
```

in React.js.

Could someone, please, explain it?

Comment: was the explanation helpful?

Comment: Yes, it was useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When working with ES6 modules, you have two types of exports:

```
export Something
export default Something
```

The difference between these is how you import them. If you have a single file with multiple modules, it makes sense to give each module a name and be able to import each of them individually, without having to import the entire contents of the file.

For example, say you have 3 modules in one file, and you export them as `export A; export B; export C;`. You can then import any one of them using the curly brackets import syntax. So `import {A, B}`, for example will import module A and B only.

The default export syntax is commonly used in React when you want to export a component, and nothing else from a file. By exporting something with `export default A`, you can import that module by using the `import X from ../file`, where X is an alias and can be anything (but usually the same name is used for consistency).

You can read more about ES6 import & export [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 17):

It totally depends on how the library is exporting objects / functions.

See the following cases:

---

Consider a library which exports this way:

```
export default func1() {...}
export func2() {...}
export func3() {...}
```

When importing from above library:

**Syntax 1**

To import `func1` we would write

```
import x from 'lib'; // x is func1
```

**Syntax 2**

To import `func2` / `func3`,

```
import {func3} from 'lib' // only func3 is imported
```

Now, if you do

**Syntax 3**

```
import * as x from 'lib';
```

You would get `x = { func2, func3, default: { func1 } }`

---

A library without default export:

```
export func1() {...}
export func2() {...}
export func3() {...}
```

Import Syntaxes:

**Syntax 1**

If we write

```
import x from 'lib'; // x is undefined, see Syntax 3
```

**Syntax 2**

To import `func2` / `func3`,

```
import {func3} from 'lib' // only func3 is imported
```

**Syntax 3**

To import all,

```
import * as x from 'lib';
```

You would get `x = { func2, func3, func1 }`

---

Now consider a library which uses `module.exports`

```
const func1 = function() { }
module.exports = func1;
```

When importing

```
import x from 'lib' // x = func1
```

---

Now consider another library:

```
const func1 = function() { }
module.exports = { func1 };
```

Now to import `func1` you would do:

```
import {func1} from 'lib';
```

---

So,
if you wish to import the complete library (or its default export) you would use

`import x from 'lib';`

If the library exports an object and you only want some keys of that object, you would use

`import {key} from 'lib';`

If you want all the keys as another object x, you would use

`import * as x from 'lib';`

Answer (score 6):

There is a huge difference though :)

import {Something} from somelib -> import specific export "Something" from the library

import Something from somelib -> import only default export and give the alias name as Somthing.