# Difference between `import { XXX} ` and import xxx

Tags: node.js

I have two classes

```
 class Page1 {
   get abc()  { return $('.btn.success'); }
 }
 export default new Page1();
```

and another class

```
 export default class Page2  {
     function abc() {
     }
  }
```

And when I import the 2 classes, what should be used. It throws error when I try

```
`import { Page1} from './page1'`
```

but works when I try

```
`import Page1 from './page1'`
```

But for the other class, when I try

```
`import Page2 from './page2'`
```

It throws error and works when I try

```
 `import {Page2} from './page2'`
```

What is the difference? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: The canonical question there should describe the issue, but I don't think you've posted your code verbatim - both of the exporting files use `export default`. You say that the named import works for the `page2` file, but the `page2` file has no named exports.

Comment: (Curly braces are used if you would like to import a non-default export.)
--> this answer from the duplicate explained it in simple words. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate , refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537180/difference-between-import-something-from-somelib-and-import-something-from